# Convert clock time to one number?

Tags: arithmetic

I have a clock time in form of HH.MM.SS (hours, minutes, sec), I need to create a way to convert it to one number so that I can determent which time is bigger.
for example 
00.00.00 is the smallest
23.59.59 is the biggest

11.03.50 > 11.02.57
etc..

I thought to do the following

hours*10000+minutes*100+sec
but im not sure it works for all cases... how can i prove it works?

Comment: Why not just convert to number of centiseconds? So if your time is $ab.cd.ef$, just do: $ef+cd*100+ab*6000$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just convert the total time to seconds.  The most seconds is clearly the "largest" time.

$$
T=3600h+60m+s
$$

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is compare two times in HH:MM:SS format, say $(h,m,s)$ and $(h',m',s')$, then you do not need to convert to seconds.  You can just use the lexicographical ordering:

\begin{align*}
(h,m,s) <_{\text{lex}} (h',m',s')
\iff &h < h', \text{ or } \\
&h = h' \mathbin{\And} m < m', \text{ or } \\
&h = h' \mathbin{\And} m = m' \mathbin{\And} s < s'.
\end{align*}

This might be more efficient that converting to seconds if each triple $(h,m,s)$ is only involved in one comparison.